# Вислови подібні до "this is not the web page you are looking for" українською

Tags: переклад, фразеологізми

Існує мем *These Are Not the Droids You Are Looking For.* GitHub обрав його для повідомлення про помилковий запит. Які подібні фрази ми маємо в нашій літературі? Хотів би знайти щось цікаве для свого сайту.

Answer (score 2):

> Обікрали... ограбили... Пропала сторінка! Краще смерть, ніж така потеря!
>
> > Карпенко-Карий, "Сто тисяч"

Comment: прекрасний варіант, якби ж тільки не слово "потеря" :)

Comment: "ограбили" теж ніби не зовісм літературний варіант. Але комедія є комедія, їй можна.